# Will UpdateWindow() send a WM_PAINT message even if the HWND is validated?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to draw an image on an `HWND` immediately (by the time the function returns, the image would have been drawn). So I am thinking of using `UpdateWindow()` to do that, as I have read, `UpdateWindow()` will send a WM_PAINT message by calling the Window Procedure directly, and not by placing a WM_PAINT message in the message queue.

But there is one think that I am not sure of, `UpdateWindow()` documentation says the following:

> If the update region is empty, no message is sent.

What does "empty" means? Does it mean validated? If so, should I call `InvalidateRect()` before calling `UpdateWindow()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no update regions marked as invalid then `UpdateWindow` does nothing, as the documentation says. If you call `InvalidateRect` first then the update region would not be empty and `UpdateWindow` would trigger a `WM_PAINT` as expected.

If you want to force a redraw to complete immediately, the easiest way is with the [`RedrawWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function. This lets you simultaneously mark a region as invalid, and force the redraw to take place before the command returns. For example, this will forcibly redraw the entire client area:

```
RedrawWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
```